# How to make a div and a footer extend to the bottom of a page and not just the window?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I've been searching on how to get a colored div on the side of my page and my footer to go all the way to the bottom of the page. I've tried to do a sticky footer but I couldn't get it to work. To see what I'm talking about go here: http://web2.nicholls.edu/maco-web-2/habitat/workfiles/trial%20fix.html
Both the light blue rectangle (the events background div) and the footer bar go to the bottom of the window, but when you scroll down,you can see that the content has extended down past them.

Here's my HTML and CSS. (I apologize if my code is super awful, this is for a class and the first website I've ever tried to build.

```css
       @charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    
    html,body { height:100%; }
    
    body {
     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     margin:0;
    
    }
    
    #navbar{
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     height:88px;
     background-color: #314d89;
     width:100%;
     z-index:75;
    }
    
    #wrapper {
     width:90%;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     position:relative;
     height:100%;;
     
    }
    
    #logo {
     position:absolute;
     margin-right:0;
     top:0;
     z-index:80;
    }
    
    #nav {
     font-size:1.25em;
     color:white;
     z-index:100;
     position:absolute;
     right:0px;
     top:60px;
    }
    
    #big-photo{
     width:100%;
     position:absolute;
     top:80px;
     background-image:url(../images/photo_01.jpg);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     height:400px;
     background-size:100%;
     z-index:50;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    
    #news{
    position:absolute;
    top:490px; 
    width:50%;
    }
     
    
    
    #events-background {
     position:absolute;
      width:35%;
      background-color: #698bd3;
      height:100%;
      top:0px;
      right:0px;
    }
    
    #upcoming-events {
     position:absolute;
     top: 490px;
     margin-right:0;
     width:30%;
     right:0px;
    }
     
    #footer-bar {
     width:100%;
     height:40px;
     background-color:#314d89;
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0px;
    
    }
    .white-header {
     color: #ffffff;
     font-weight:300;
     text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:2em;
    }
    .green-header {
     color: #84d67b;
     font-weight:300;
     font-size:2em;
     text-transform:uppercase;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org

    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="trial fix css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="navbar"> </div>
    <div id="big-photo"> </div>
    <div id="events-background"> </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav"> ABOUT | VOLUNTEER | APPLY | RESTORE | CALENDAR | GALLERY | CONTACT </div>
    <div id="logo"><img src="../images/fixed-logo_02.png" width="295" height="148" alt="Bayou Habitat for Humanity Logo" /> < </div>
    
    <div id="news"> <h2 class="green-header"> HABITAT NEWS </h2> <p> Volunteer Day </p> <p> Volunteer Day is Saturday, December 14th, at the Habitat for humanity site in Thibodaux.
    
    Having the details of its syndication contracts and movie packages exposed could potentially put millions of dollars in future deals at risk. All of these little, individual show and movie deals actually add up to billions of dollars in revenue for Sony Pictures annually. To be sure, while a 2009 cash licensing deal of $26,600 from a television station in Detroit for 133 episodes of Good Times to be aired from September 2009–2010 doesn’t seem like a ton of money, the fact that Sony was still banking cash from a show 35 years after it aired speaks to the revenue-generating capabilities of library content. (Good Times aired its last original episode in 1979.)
    
    Now think about how much potential revenue Seinfeld, not to mention Jeopardy and Wheel of Fortune, which Sony Pictures also produces, is capable of generating over the next two decades and how much of that could be left on the table as a result of the leak.
    
    That’s the frightening scenario Sony Pictures now faces, at a time when it is trying to increase its annual revenue to $11 billion by 2018 from $8 billion now.
     </p></div>
    <div id="upcoming-events"> <h2 class="white-header"> Upcoming Events </h2> 
    <p> Christmas Toy Drive </p> </div>
    
    <div id="statement"> We are pledged to the letter and spirit of U.S. policy for the achievement of equal housing opportunity throughout the nation. We encourage and support an affirmative advertising and marketing program in which there are no barriers to obtaining housing because of race, color, religion, sex, handicap, familial status, national origin, age, marital status, sexual orientation, or sources of income.  </div>
    <div id="about" >© 2014 Bayou Area Habitat for Humanity
    [ phone: (985) 447-6999 ] [ Contact via Email ]
    [ Privacy Policy ] </div>
    <div id="newsletter"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-bar"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:fixed` to the element and `bottom: 0px;`

or

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```